# How to find max occurence of a record's field in multiple rows?

Tags: python, django

The problem I am facing right now is related to finding frequency of a record's field in multiple rows.

For example, let's assume, we have 6 records.

```
Zone     Camera    Ip
----     ------    --
Zone 1   Cam 1    192.16.....
Zone 2   Cam 2    192.16.....
Zone 4   Cam 3    192.16.....
Zone 2   Cam 4    192.16.....
Zone 2   Cam 5    192.16.....
Zone 3   Cam 6    192.16.....
```

Here we want to find Max frequency of Zone or what is the most frequent Zone among the records? (Normally, we can see the Zone 2 happened for 3 times which is the most frequent zone)

I used aggregate function to find the Max but it doesn't work that way as it only returns the max pk of the field.

Failed example that I tried:

```
qs.aggregate(most_frequent_zone=Max('Zone'),...)
```

Is there any built-in way to handle this scenario? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain the result by ***group by*** operation along with a ***aggregation***

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max

qs.values('Zone').annotate(zone_count=Count('Zone')).aggregate(most_frequent_zone=Max('zone_count'))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your attempt. `qs.values('Zone').annotate(count=Count('Zone'))` solves part of the problem but `.aggregate(most_frequent_zone=Max('Zone'))` yet returns the max pk rather than max count. I did try with `.aggregate(most_frequent_zone=Max('count'))` it actually returns the desired most_frequent_zone's frequency but how to return the zone as well?

Comment: can you share the model?

Comment: I apologize. Due to team policy, I can't share the model but I have simulated the complete scenario here: https://pastebin.com/R30V6BYE

Comment: If you don't accept my edits, least update your answer with
`qs.values('Zone').annotate(count=Count('Zone')).aggregate(most_frequent_zone=Max('count'))`, Please.